# Angular: entering text into an input box, saving it in an ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input box and when some text is added to it I want it to be stored in the ng-model

This is what I'm trying to do but not sure is working (using ng-change directive):

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.userAge" ng-change="checkAge()">
```

...in my controller:

```
this.userAge;

this.checkAge = function() {
    console.log(this.userAge);
}
```

Comment: any error in console or what's happening? you might change to myCtrl.checkAge()

Comment: Of course it's not causing the issue, @maddog.. @NewToJS, you must post your complete view, maybe you aren't using the `controllerAsSyntax` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe your ng-change needs to be

```
ng-change="myCtrl.checkAge()"
```

And make sure you have ng-controller="myControllerName as myCtrl" somewhere on a parent element.

Answer (score 1):

myCtrl.checkAge() instead of just checkAge()

The scope of this also changes inside the function so the log wont work.

```
var ctrl = this;

ctrl.userAge;

ctrl.checkAge = function() {
    console.log(ctrl.userAge);
}
```